# TestLink: Report format dropdown excel is missing

Tags: testlink

I am Using testlink 1.9.12. When I go to reports and metrics and in report format dropdown, I cannot find excel. Only options there are HTML, Psuedo WORD and HTML[email].

I checked but didn't get any relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

The following reports can be downloaded in excel format

- Test result matrix
- Failed Test Cases
- Blocked Test Cases
- Not run Test Cases